# Default browser in MMC

Tags: windows-10, browser, default-settings, mmc

Can I change the built-in browser used by MMC? Currently it's using Internet Explorer. I am using Windows 10. I would prefer to use Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MMC uses the default browser to open hyperlinks. To set Chrome as the default browser, open Settings <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, System, Default Apps. Select Google Chrome as the default Web browser.

Comment: I tried that, its still using internet explorer, not Chrome

Comment: Which hyperlink are you clicking on? I'll try to repro that here.

Comment: Not a hyperlink, the built in browser, MMC -> File -> Add/Remove Snap-in -> Link to Web Address, that snap-in, then loads using Internet Explorer

Comment: In that case... I don't think it can be forced to use a different browser, as MMC uses the core DLLs (ieframe.dll or mshtml.dll) to render the page instead of launching the browser's executable.